# VBA macro that compares one row and sees if it exist in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create VBA code that checks row by row if one row exists in another workbook and does it repeatedly until it runs out of rows to check in another workbook. Then for each row it finds that doesn't exist send a copy of it to a new workbook. I've tried searching for this for weeks but everyone want just to check if a single row exist, I need to check 500k rows exist in another workbook.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim varSheetA As Variant
Dim varSheetB As Variant
Dim strRangeToCheck As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long


nlin = 1
ncol = 1

'Get the worksheets from the workbooks
Set wbkA = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename)
Set varSheetA = wbkA.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' or whatever sheet you need

Set wbkB = Workbooks.Open(Application.GetOpenFilename)
Set varSheetB = wbkB.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' or whatever sheet you need

strRangeToCheck = "A1:A999999"
' If you know the data will only be in a smaller range, reduce the size of the ranges above.
Debug.Print Now
varSheetA = varSheetA.Range(strRangeToCheck)
varSheetB = varSheetB.Range(strRangeToCheck)
Debug.Print Now


Dim ws As Variant

'Set lol = Workbooks.Open("LOL.xlsm")
Set ws = Workbooks.Add.Sheets("Sheet1")

For iRow = LBound(varSheetA, 1) To UBound(varSheetA, 1)
    For iCol = LBound(varSheetA, 2) To UBound(varSheetA, 2)
        If varSheetA(iRow, iCol) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) Then
            ' Cells are identical.
            ' Do nothing.
        Else

            ws.Cells(nlin, ncol + 1) = varSheetA(iRow, iCol) 'Gives me the value in workbookA
            ws.Cells(nlin, ncol + 2) = varSheetB(iRow, iCol) 'Gives me the value in workbookB

            nlin = nlin + 1

        End If
    Next
Next
ws.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

This is what I had but it only checks differences among the same row which is not what I want.

Comment: What's wrong with COUNTIFS?

Comment: How many rows in each worksheet? How many columns? I'm guessing that they are the same number of columns in each but how many are there?

Comment: Depending on the volume of rows and columns, it could be much quicker to add a helper column in each book where you concatenate all columns, then spread a "MATCH" function down the range to check if any rows are identical?

Comment: its 1 million rows per sheet. I moved it to an access database with the vba codes and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not such a "cody" way to do things, more like manipulating Excel spreadsheets with helper columns, but with screenupdating set to false it is MUCH MUCH quicker than looping through rows and columns and checking boolean operations for each row and cell against a 2nd sheet. This is just an example for two worksheets doing 1000 rows and I've left out the declarations and actually copying just to highlight the technique:

```
ws1.Range("D1:D1000").Formula = ("=A1&B1&C1")
ws2.Range("D1:D1000").Formula = ("=A1&B1&C1")

ws1.Range("E1:E1000").Formula = ("=IFERROR(MATCH(D1,'" & ws2.Name & "'!D:D,0),"""")")

For Each c In ws1.Range("E1:E20")
    If c.Value = "" Then ' copy row to another sheet 
Next c
```